# Ext.grid.Grid not displaying correctly without specified widths

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I'm trying to display an `Ext.grid.Grid` and fit it to a page. Ideally I'd like to use the flex configuration to make certain columns proportionally wider. But this does not work. The image below is the grid with flex added to the columns with no widths.

[image]

```
columns: [
    { text: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name'},
    { text: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email' },
    { text: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone' }
],
```

If I specify widths on the columns I get the following:
[image]

```
columns: [
    { text: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name', width: 100 },
    { text: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', width: 230 },
    { text: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone', width: 150 }
],
```

Is there any other way to get the grid to display properly and hopefully fit to the surrounding panel, making the columns stretch to fit?

Comment: `flex` is exactly what you want. Do you have additional CSS affecting the display of the grid?

Comment: Flex doesn't appear to work with Ext.grid.Grid in the modern toolkit. I'm using Ext 6 Beta, but the modern toolkit is mostly sencha touch, I think.

Comment: Maybe you have to set `layout: 'hbox'` manually for makes `flex` work?

Comment: That just causes the error: The base layout for a DataView must always be a Fit Layout. It just seems like the Ext.grid.Grid is broken.